# Windows service only gets called when Visual Studio is attached to process

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, service

I've created a simple windows service in C# using Visual Studio 2010.  It uses a TcpListener and socket to listen for messages on a given port.  This worked absolutely perfectly when my laptop had Windows Vista on it.  However, since upgrading to Windows 7 and re-installing my service it only responds if I'm attached to the process and debugging in Visual Studio 2010 - at which time it behaves as expected.

I've tried running the service under my (administrator) credentials and setting the exe to run as administrator.  I've also checked "Allow service to interact with desktop" when it was running under the Local System account.

I'm testing using both a test console app and an Adobe Air application - both with the same results.

Are there some specific permissions that I need to allow the service to be called?

Comment: that might be the first time the words "Windows Vista" and "perfectly" were ever used in the same sentence! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an exception for your executable in Windows Firewall.

Comment: I've just given that a go, for both inbound and outbound, but unfortunately it hasn't worked.  I've tried turning off the firewall completely too but it still behaves the same.